# Instagram api - timestamp for photos by hashtag

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I have got this feed.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/.../media/recent?min_timestamp=1432429690&max_timestamp=1432429790&client_id=...
```

But it still takes everything. So my question is, is there any option to get photos by hashtag by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

media tags API does not support `min_timestamp` and `max_timestamp`

```
https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent
```

You cannot currently filter hashtag photos by data/time